# How Loop a Slideshow using jquery

Tags: jquery

Basically i am trying to create slideshow using jquery. Here the slideshow navigation is working fine but the Slideshow looping is not working. 
I have tried here my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/GfpHz/2/)** 
my script is:

```
 var currIndex = -1;

 function slideshow(slideshowId){
     var len=$("ul#"+slideshowId+" li.slides").length;
     currIndex = (currIndex + 1) % len;
     $("ul#"+slideshowId+" li.slides").hide();
     $("ul#"+slideshowId+" li.slide"+currIndex+"").fadeIn();     
 }

 function slidepagenation(slideshowId,slideno){    
        $("ul#"+slideshowId+" li.slides").hide();
        $("ul#"+slideshowId+" li.slide"+slideno+"").fadeIn();
        currIndex = slideno;
 }

var tshone = 0;
var tshtwo = 0;

    slideshow('slideshow-one');
    tshone =setInterval(slideshow('slideshow-one'), 500);
     slideshow('slideshow-two');
    tshtwo =setInterval(slideshow('slideshow-two'), 500);

    $('ul.slideshow-one li a').click(function(){
        clearInterval(tshone);
        var element = $(this);
        var slideshowid=element.parent().parent().attr('class');
        var slideno = $("ul.slideshow-one li a").index($(this));
        slidepagenation(slideshowid,slideno); 
    });

    $('ul.slideshow-two li a').click(function(){
        clearInterval(tshtwo);
        var element = $(this);
        var slideshowid=element.parent().parent().attr('class');
        var slideno = $("ul.slideshow-two li a").index($(this));
        slidepagenation(slideshowid,slideno); 
    });
```

​My html is here :

```
<ul class="slideshow" id="slideshow-one">
    <li class="slides slide0" style="display:block">
    Slide one
    </li>
    <li class="slides slide1">
    Slide two
    </li>
    <li class="slides slide2">
    Slide three
    </li>     
</ul>
<div class="full-length clearfix txt-center">
<ul class="slideshow-one">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li> 
    <li><a>3</a></li>     
</ul>
</div>
<br><br>
<ul class="slideshow" id="slideshow-two">
    <li class="slides slide0" style="display:block">
    Slide one
    </li>
    <li class="slides slide1">
    Slide two
    </li>    
</ul>
<div class="full-length clearfix txt-center">
<ul class="slideshow-two">
    <li><a>1</a></li>
    <li><a>2</a></li>    
</ul>
</div>
```

​

Comment: You're trying to use a single `currIndex` variable to keep track of two slideshows. (Plus what TJ said below.) Also, why repeat the `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` in both functions? Call `slidepagenation(slideShowId,(currIndex + 1) % len)` from within `slideshow()`.

Comment: Why not use one of the 50 already created slideshow plugins?

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` accepts a *function* to run on the interval, but you're giving it `undefined`:

```
tshone =setInterval(slideshow('slideshow-one'), 500);
```

...because that line *calls* `slideshow` and passes its return value to `setInterval`. Since `slideshow` doesn't return a value, the result of calling it is `undefined`.

Instead:

```
tshone =setInterval(function() {
    slideshow('slideshow-one');
}, 500);
```

Now we're creating a function and passing that to `setInterval`. The function calls `slideshow` every half second.

Also note that you're using just **one** `currIndex`, but you're trying to use it with two different slideshows. That's not going to work. I'd recommend eliminating `currIndex` entirely and just figuring out from the DOM which slide is active. Something like this:

```
function slideshow(slideshowId){
    var slideShow = $("ul#"+slideshowId);
    var slide;

    slide = slideShow.find("li.slides:visible");
    if (slide.length > 1) {
        slide.hide();
        slide = $();
    }
    slide = slide.hide().nextAll("li.slides").first();
    if (slide.length == 0) {
        slide = slideShow.find("li.slides").first();
    }
    slide.fadeIn();
}
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried what you have suggest but it's showing some other problem please here check this http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/GfpHz/3/

Comment: @SureshPattu: "some other problem" is not a useful description.

Comment: @SureshPattu: "not working properly" is no more informative than "some other problem". But I did edit earlier to tell you what the problem was and how to fix it, and I've just added some sample code.